# Unable to click login button of Microsoft account of my angularjs application with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

Following code for microsoft account login not working:

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.css("#cred_userid_inputtext")).sendKeys("suyash@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com");
browser.driver.findElement(By.css("#cred_password_inputtext")).sendKeys("xxxx2");
browser.driver.findElement(By.id('cred_sign_in_button')).click();
browser.driver.findElement(By.id('cred_sign_in_button')).click(); browser.driver.sleep(5000);
```

I am using Chrome 64 bit browser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the global `browser.driver...` selector method, try using this concatenated syntax.

`$('#cred_sign_in_button).click();`

the `$(..)` is short hand for `element(by.css(..`
more examples ->http://luxiyalu.com/protractor-locators-selectors/

Protractor has a number of different ways you can select an attribute.Would you mind posting the HTML element for the button you are trying to select?

Comment: Jquery doesnt work with protractor .seeking for some other solution

Comment: If you looked at the article I linked in my answer you'd see it's not jQuery :)

**"The $ is not a jQuery selector, but a shorthanded version of element(by.css('#some-id')). In this fashion, we’d be able to select elements by id, class and attributes"**

Answer (score 0):

Use directly protractor methods if it is Angular
like
element(by.model('ios'));
element(by.id('android')); etc.,
and use implicit wait until element is preset https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.
Can you post the error and html so that we will have big picture.